# AppEngine Application is missing

Tags: google-app-engine

I just created my apps account, and created my app engine application, yesterday. I used Eclipse to upload my app and everything was wonderful yesterday. Today... the application is missing. I log into my appengine account and my app is no longer listed; I only see the "create application" button. I tried creating the app again, with the same ID, but I get the "invalid" message. Despite all this, I'm able to bring up my site via the main-domain.appspot.com. Please help. Why can't I see my app in the appengine console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you're logged into a different account. This can happen sometimes if there was confusion about mutli-login. Try these steps to find your application:

1. Open a fresh incognito or private browsing window
2. Go to http://appspot.com and log into one Google account
3. See if your application is listed. If not, close your private browsing window to clear the session, and try it again for one of your other accounts.

Once you've found your application, it may be owned by the wrong account. You can fix this by moving ownership to your preferred account.

1. Navigate to the dashboard for your application.
2. On the left side menu click 'Permissions' under 'Administration'.
3. Add your preferred account as an owner.
4. Log into your preferred account and check your email. You will need to accept an invitation to take ownership of the application.
5. Reload the permissions page on the application dashboard. You should see both accounts listed as owners.
6. Remove any unwanted accounts from the owners list. (Remember, you need at least one owner!)

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. I had a previous Google account that's for personal use. I don't know what happened, but somehow I guess I created that app under my personal account. However, when I go to appengine.google.com/mydomain and use my log in I create for that, I'm unable to see my app. Is there a way to straighten this out, or do I just leave it?

Comment: Yup, you can fix this. I added it to the answer because it's a bit more expressive.

Comment: First step is to complete my domain transfer so I can gain access to my email. That's what I was trying to do when I encountered this issue. Thank you again for your help. You're actually in my G+ circles. I should have just gone straight to you ;o)

Comment: I have the same problem. I created the app a couple of weeks ago to secure it, but left it undeployed. Now I no longer can see it, and none of the methods here work either. :/